# Using pandas .map to change values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to change the strings in my data do numerical value using map function.

This is the data:

```
    label   sms_message
0   ham     Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only ...
1   ham     Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
2   spam    Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...
3   ham     U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
4   ham     Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro...
```

I'm trying to change 'spam' to 1 and 'ham' to 0 using this:

```
df['label'] = df.label.map({'ham':0, 'spam':1})
```

But the result is:

```
    label   sms_message
0   NaN     Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only ...
1   NaN     Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
2   NaN     Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...
3   NaN     U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
4   NaN     Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro...
```

Do anyone can identify the problem?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: But the label turns to NaN instead of 1 or 0.

Comment: Check it has blank in columns or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, I think you executed the same statement twice (1 after 1). The following statements executed on Python interactive terminal clarifies that.

> **Note:** If you pass dictionary, map() replaces all values from Series with `NaN` 
>   if it does not match with dictionary's keys (I think, you have also done the same i.e. executing the statement twice). Check [pandas map(), apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).
>
> **Pandas documentation note**: when *arg* is a dictionary, values in *Series* that are not in the dictionary (as keys) are converted to *NaN*.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> d = {
...     "label": ["ham", "ham", "spam", "ham", "ham"],
...     "sms_messsage": [
...     "Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only ...",
...     "Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...",
...     "Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...",
...     "U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...",
...     "Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro..."
...    ]
... }
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
  label                                       sms_messsage
0   ham  Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only ...
1   ham                      Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
2  spam  Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...
3   ham  U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
4   ham  Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro...
>>>
>>> df['label'] = df.label.map({'ham':0, 'spam':1})
>>> df
   label                                       sms_messsage
0      0  Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only ...
1      0                      Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
2      1  Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...
3      0  U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
4      0  Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro...
>>>
>>> df['label'] = df.label.map({'ham':0, 'spam':1})
>>> df
   label                                       sms_messsage
0    NaN  Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only ...
1    NaN                      Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
2    NaN  Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...
3    NaN  U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
4    NaN  Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro...
>>>
```

#### Other ways to obtain the same result

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> d = {
...     "label": ['spam', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'spam'],
...     "sms_message": ["M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5"]
... }
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
  label sms_message
0  spam          M1
1   ham          M2
2   ham          M3
3   ham          M4
4  spam          M5
>>>
```

> 1st way - using `map()` with `dictionary` parameter

```
>>> new_values = {'spam': 1, 'ham': 0}
>>>
>>> df
  label sms_message
0  spam          M1
1   ham          M2
2   ham          M3
3   ham          M4
4  spam          M5
>>>
>>> df.label = df.label.map(new_values)
>>> df
   label sms_message
0      1          M1
1      0          M2
2      0          M3
3      0          M4
4      1          M5
>>>
```

> 2nd way - using `map()` with `function` parameter

```
>>> df.label = df.label.map(lambda v: 0 if v == 'ham' else 1)
>>> df
   label sms_message
0      1          M1
1      0          M2
2      0          M3
3      0          M4
4      1          M5
>>>
```

> 3rd way - using `apply()` with `function` parameter

```
>>> df.label = df.label.apply(lambda v: 0 if v == "ham" else 1)
>>>
>>> df
   label sms_message
0      1          M1
1      0          M2
2      0          M3
3      0          M4
4      1          M5
>>>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your issue is with read_table function.

Try do it:

```
df = pd.read_table('smsspamcollection/SMSSpamCollection',
                   sep='\t', 
                   header=None,
                   names=['label', 'sms_message'])
```

Answer (score 0):

may be because your data has not headers Solution:

**try to do**

```
df.columns = [ "label", "message"]
ham_spam= {'spam': 1, 'ham': 0}
df['label'] = df.label.map(ham_spam )
df
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).